# Is this an equivalent definition for connectivity in graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, graph-connectivity

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph. The usual definition of connectivity is:

> $G$ is connected iff for each pair of vertices $u,v\in V$, there exists a path between $u$ and $v$.

I am fine with this definition, but I wanted to know if this definition is equivalent:

> $G$ is connected iff there do not exist nonempty disjoint subsets $V_1,V_2$ of $V$ such that $V=V_1\cup V_2$ and there is no edge $uv\in E$ with $u\in V_1$ and $v\in V_2$.

My definition is more topologically motivated - we can think of $(V_1,V_2)$ as a separation of $G$. My intuition is that these definitions are equivalent, and I cannot see any reason why they would not be, but I do not believe I have seen the latter be used e.g. in a textbook or lecture. Is it the case that they are not equivalent, or just that the former is more intuitive?

Comment: They are both equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose in addition that $V_1,V_2$ are non-empty and their union is the entire graph (as pointed out in the other answer, these assumptions are necessary).

To show that they are equivalent, first observe that if the "no cut" definition holds, then there can be no path from any vertex in $V_1$ to any vertex in $V_2$. Indeed, if there were such a path - call it $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ - then let $k$ be maximal such that $w_k$ is in $V_1$. It follows that $k<n$ and $w_{k+1}$ is in $V_2$, a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose the the first condition holds. Then, choose $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$ arbitrarily and choose an arbitrary path from $v_1$ to $v_2$. As before, consider the maximal vertex in the path that is still in $V_1$. Then it is adjacent to a vertex of $V_2$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any insight into why this definition is not more commonly used?

Comment: I suppose some graph theorists may have a preference to use paths instead of cuts. They are dual to each other in a suitable sense. On the other hand, graphs are examples of CW complexes, in which case the topological definition of connectedness translates directly into your "no cuts" definition of connectedness. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex#Examples

Comment: In practice, the cut definition gets used implicitly all the time when proving that a graph is not connected. But if you want to use the fact that a graph *is* connected, you'd rather take the definition that begins "there exists..." than the definition that begins "there does not exist..." since that lets you conclude something immediately.

Comment: @pre-kidney Thanks for the motivation. I'm afraid my topological knowledge is insufficient to fully understand the definition of a CW complex, but I will get there some day :)

Comment: The full blown definition is overkill for this application. In $1$-dimension, a CW-complex is a topological space formed by glueing together $0$-cells (i.e. points) and $1$-cells (i.e. segments of curves). Just the same way a graph is a bunch of vertices glued to edges. Now if you go to higher dimensions, you can start attaching spheres etc. as your higher dimensional cells, and building up a mosiac of more interesting manifolds.

Comment: @pre-kidney Thanks for the simplified definition of a CW-complex. That is intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that both the subsets must be non-empty. Also, you need to specify that $V_1\cup V_2=V$. (These requirements both have analogous counterparts in the topological definition, so they shouldn't feel too foreign.)

Once you add these two requirements, then yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, indeed I meant nonempty disjoint subsets that partition the vertex set. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do you have any insight into why this definition is not more commonly used? I am afraid my knowledge of (algebraic) topology is not sufficient to full understand the definition of a topology on a graph, but it seems like this definition would generalize better to notions of connectivity in other fields of mathematics.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't. Possibly because graph theorists for some reason like paths more than they like partitioning the vertex set. (Do they? I don't know.) Or it was the first definition used in some influential paper, and it just stuck. I mean, it's nice that people agree on a single definition. That's a luxury many don't have. Heck, often the competing definitions aren't even equivalent.