# "Dual" definition of 1-connectivity in finite simplicial complex?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, simplicial-complex

I am studying the concepts of finite simplicial complexes (so please forgive for any mistakes :)) and, in particular, trying to grasp the concept of higher-order connectedness.

I have the following intuition from graph theory. We can define connected graphs in the following two equivalent ways (see [Is this an equivalent definition for connectivity in graphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472102/is-this-an-equivalent-definition-for-connectivity-in-graphs) )

1. $G$ is connected iff for all pairs of vertices $u,v \in V$, there exists a path between $u$ and $v$.
2. $G$ is connected iff for all partitions $\{A,B\}$ of $V(G)$ in two non-empty parts, there exists an edge with one endpoint in $A$ and the other in $B$.

My impression is that, using a topological point of view, we can view a graph $G$ as a $1$-dimensional simplicial complex, and "graph connectivity" is equivalent to the $0$-connectivity (or path connectivity) of this complex, i.e. for each continuous map $f: S^0 \rightarrow G$ can be extended to a continuous map $\overline{f}: B^1 \rightarrow G$. The parallel is clear with the first definition of graph connectivity.

Now, considering $1$-connectivity in a finite simplicial complex $X$ (i.e. each continuous map $f: S^1 \rightarrow X$ can be extended to a continuous map $\overline{f}: B^2 \rightarrow X$), I wonder if there is "more combinatorial" way of expressing that property in such a way that is more similar to the definitions for graph-connectivity I gave earlier.

For instance, I kind of visualize this property as (being vague here) saying that any "cycle" $C$ in $X$ we can find some "surface" in $X$ with $C$ as its border. But at the moment I don't imagine something which is analogous to the definition of connectivity in graphs in terms of its "cuts", that is, a partition of the vertices which "separate" the graph somehow.

So my question is, does such a "dual" definition of $1$-connectivity exist? If so, how it is formalised? Can it be understood in combinatorial terms like the cuts in graphs?

Answer (score 2):

The usual "$1$-connectedness" analogue of your property 1 is that any cycle of edges in the 1-skeleton extends to a [Van Kampen diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram).

But I don't know of an analogue of your property 2.